# How to sync node_modules with actual package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

For example if I've switched branch with git and want to sync `node_modules` with current `package.json`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If your new branch has new npm packages or updated version dependencies, just run `$ npm install` again after switching branches.

If your new branch removes npm packages from package.json, run `$ npm prune`

Comment: after running npm install in this case I've stucked with "shasum check failed". Can it be connected with this? Are you sure npm install is valid in such case?

Comment: I'm positive `npm install` is valid in these cases. You can always try deleting your `node_modules` folder and re-running `npm install`. Also this thread may pertain to your issue.

Answer (score 2):

We can make use of [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) to run the `npm install` automatically when *package.json* changes when we pull or checkout to different branch.

Here is the script that needs to be executed. We basically check whether *package.json* file is present in the diff.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

changed_files="$(git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD)"

check_run() {
    echo "$changed_files" | grep --quiet "$1" && eval "$2"
}

check_run package.json "npm install"
```

To run the above script on

- git pull - Run `chmod +x post-merge` to make it executable then `mv post-merge .git/hooks/` put it into git hooks.
- git checkout - Run `chmod +x post-checkout` and then `mv post-checkout .git/hooks/`

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` will install latest versions of packages from `packages.json` which is often not the desired behaviour.

When you switch between branches most likely you want the versions fixed in `package-lock.json`. Since npm 5.7.0 there is a special command `npm ci` which does that.

More details in [Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)

Answer (score 0):

First run this command to find outdated packages:

```
npm outdated -g --depth=0
```

Then use this command to update the outdated packages:

```
npm update -g <package_name>
```