# How should I handle package-lock.json when I deploy from git via ssh?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, npm

I have a deployment process where I check code into a git repository, and via web hooks a deployment script is run on the production server. On that server, I connect to git using ssh and a .pem key, pull from git, npm install, build webpack and restart the service process.

I never intend to commit anything from the prod servers - they should be able to deploy automatically. However, this does not work, because the `package-lock.json` file is frequently updated when I run `npm install`, and so the next time I deploy, the `git pull` step fails, saying that I conflict with existing `package-lock.json` file because it has changes that are not committed.

My current solution is to .gitignore the package-lock.json file. But that defeats its purpose, to provide builds that are identical to the ones on my dev machine.

What would be the right way to handle `package-lock.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [helpful StackOverflow Question/Answer about why your package.lock is changing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json). The closest most useful answer seems to reference an [NPM bug that's seeing much activity here in October 2017](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18286).

But currently, `package.json` overrides `package-lock.json`, meaning if you use `~2.1` and there's a 2.2 version of that package, your production deploy will get upgraded.

Assuming you're not from the future, there's two different ideas here:

1. Use only non-prefixed, specific version numbers (2.1 vs ~2.0) in your package.json. (This is not great)
2. `npm install --no-save`... which doesn't solve the underlaying issue of lock files getting ignored, but I *think* will keep the `package-lock.json` from being updated.

Comment: Could you say a bit about why #1 is "not great"? Especially when reproducibility of builds is very important, and package-lock doesn't lock.