# npm - How to actually use package-lock.json for installing based on locked versions?

Tags: npm

Just updated from npm 3 to 5, to use this feature.

Sorry, I must be missing something totally obvious, but how do make npm respect the pinned versions in **package-lock.json** file when installing?

Let's say I have a `package.json` with a fair bit of outdated packages.  Doing an `npm install` will pull in new stuff and breaks my app.

For example, the main package I want to stabilize is `bootstrap` - I want to block its version at **bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6** for now, but `npm install` finds **4.0.0-beta.28**.

If I `npm update` any package, **package-lock.json** gets updated.

#### Let's go to my development directory.

This is my package.json entry for bootstrap:

`"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6"`

And this is what I see for my installed packages and meta data:

```
$ npm list 2>/dev/null | grep bootstrap
├─┬ bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
├─┬ bootstrap-vue@0.16.1
│ ├── bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6 deduped


(env) jluc@py$ grep bootstrap package.json package-lock.json
package.json:    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
package.json:    "bootstrap-vue": "^0.16.1",
package-lock.json:    "bootstrap": {
package-lock.json:      "version": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.tgz",
package-lock.json:    "bootstrap-vue": {
package-lock.json:      "version": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-vue/-/bootstrap-vue-0.16.1.tgz",
package-lock.json:        "bootstrap": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6.tgz",
```

Looks good.  Lock is **bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha.6**.

#### But how I use actually use that **package-lock.json**?

Here's what I did:

- created a brand new directory
- copied in **package.json** and **package-lock.json**
- ran `npm install`.

No good.  npm again found bootstrap beta and **package-lock.json** had no effect, in fact it was rewritten from what `npm install` did.   Which is consistent with the behavior you want in dev, but doesn't tell me how I would use the lockfile to stabilize my packages.

```
(env) jluc@trynpmlock$ npm list 2>/dev/null | grep bootstrap
├── bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2
├─┬ bootstrap-vue@0.16.1
│ ├── bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 deduped

(env) jluc@trynpmlock$ grep bootstrap package.json package-lock.json
package.json:    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
package.json:    "bootstrap-vue": "^0.16.1",
package-lock.json:    "bootstrap": {
package-lock.json:      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap/-/bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.2.tgz",
package-lock.json:    "bootstrap-vue": {
package-lock.json:      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap-vue/-/bootstrap-vue-0.16.1.tgz",
package-lock.json:        "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
```

- If I delete the **package.json** and only have a directory with **package-lock.json**, then `npm install` installs very little and leaves me with a truncated **package-lock.json**
- npm install has a `--no-package-lock` option, but that prevents updating the **package-lock.json**.

Basically how do I tell npm *install everything from package.json, but respect locks in package-lock.json*?  Do I use a different command than `npm install`?  Is it because npm install's doc refers to locks in the context of a package installation, but locks don't apply when you install the package.json in its entirety?

Yes, I know I can specify `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"`, minus the `^`, to pin the version manually.

**My environment:**

```
(env) jluc@py$ npm -v
5.5.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)

Comment: @ford04  not really, no.  I was concerned here with the end result, getting npm to respect the locks, not so much with `npm install`s specific behavior.  Notice how the title is phrased. Plus, when I wrote this question, there was no `npm ci` mentioned in the linked question's accepted answer so it did not answer my question at the time (I might even have looked it over then).  Seems to me there is no great harm in leaving another breadcrumb question to find `npm ci`, unless the npm doc about locks has become strikingly limpid and clear.

Comment: Yet another `npm ci` related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You need to use the `npm ci` command to install from `package-lock.json`.

See: https://blog.npmjs.org/post/171556855892/introducing-npm-ci-for-faster-more-reliable

Comment: This is interesting.  Busy with somethinh else but will defintitely check it out.  Makes sense that theyd have something, just wish it had been clearer.

Comment: This fails if I don't have a package.json file... `ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/chris/fuck3/package.json'`

Comment: I've switched this over to be accepted, because it seems to do pretty much what I was asking for, even if @Volti s answer was correct at the time - this command came after.

Comment: When running `npm ci` you need to be sure that you have both `package.json` file and `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 27):

**Update**: As [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/491752/dave-potts) pointed out, the command for this situation is now `npm ci`.  It will install from `package-lock.json` and will not update it. See [the documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) for more information.

---

According to [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17979#issuecomment-332701215) by a [member of the npm CLI team](https://github.com/iarna), what you are describing is a "high priority bug".

> 1. If you have a package.json and you run `npm i` we generate a package-lock.json from it.
> 2. If you run `npm i` against that package.json and package-lock.json, the latter will never be updated, even if the package.json would be happy with newer versions.
> 3. If you manually edit your package.json to have different ranges and run `npm i` and those ranges aren't compatible with your package-lock.json then the latter will be updated with version that are compatible with your package.json. Further runs of `npm i` will be as with 2 above.
>
> If you do run into a case where npm@^5.4.2 mutates a package-lock.json that was otherwise compatible with the paired package.json please open a new issue. This sort of thing would constitute a high priority bug.

Comment: So, then, if I understand you correctly, your position is that **package-lock.json** does NOT, in fact, provide the services it is expected, and advertised to do?  I.e. it can't be relied upon to install based on the exact versions that were saved in it the last time it was updated (if that is the case, what does this feature provide besides promoting false expectations????).  

One reason for my confusion is all these questions seem to get lumped into *why does package.json get rewritten?*.  That's not the real issue - the real issue is *why is it not **used** *.

Comment: If you rephrase your answer to specify that lock can't be used to install from it (a quote from an authoritative person in the github issue would be nice if you can get it) - I am inclined to grant you the bounty.  My one worry is a) if you're wrong - after all this goes against any reasonable expectations and b) if that situation changes.  So, I'd in any case wait till the last minute for rebuttals and I'd want to remove this answer if this behiavor gets fixed.  Fair?  Don't care that much about cipm, core npm behavior is what I care about.

Comment: I kinda hope I am wrong ;-)  I'm with you, lets get to the bottom of this.

Comment: I re-read your question and realized that you weren't changing the package.json in the process... my apologies.  According to the same GitHub issue thread, that behavior is a bug.

Comment: alright accepted.  if it turns out to be the wrong answer, I am totally open to revisiting this to  avoid confusion.  but for now it seems that **package-lock.json**, by itself, does not enforce stability.

Comment: so, package-lock.json should work??? how? I've only really seen the `npm install` side of things document, which, to my understanding reads **package.json** and updates **package-lock.json**.  I haven't seen anywhere yet how package-lock.json gets **used**, rather than **written to**.

Comment: According to what I've read, if you don't actually edit package.json, package-lock.json shouldn't be updated assuming you are using an NPM version 5.4.2 or better.  Since you said you are using 5.5.1 and you aren't changing your package.json file, I think you have a bug...

Comment: hmmm.  so how would you test expected behavior?  I am thinking:  1. `npm install` 2 _outdated_ packages (by specifiying versions).  2. `npm update` one of them.  that leaves package-lock version alone for the other.  3.  copy package.json and package-lock.json to a new directory.  4.  `npm install` - from what you said, I should have the updated package to latest version but the other obsolete package should have been fetched as per the package-lock which is the old version.  Am I understanding the intent correctly?  I might need to unpin versions after the first install.

Comment: all in all, I am finding it very hard to believe I am hitting a bug on such a high profile feature, as opposed to not using npm correctly.

Comment: Wonder if/how we could switch to Dave Potts’s answer?  Looks like it solves the question, I’ve already successfully written it into my own Ansible configs.  Do you think it works?  My understanding is that your bounty’s yours by now, as it should be.

Comment: hey, sorry, just realized I didn't DM you on my last comment.  What do you think of switching over?  From this, it seems to be an npm 5.7.1+ thingy:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52499617/what-is-the-difference-between-npm-install-and-npm-ci

Comment: I changed this one as well.  When I answered this originally, `npm ci` wasn't a thing.  It was added in 5.7.  Feel free to switch the accepted answer to his.  Either way, `npm ci` solves the issues you were having.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to work

`npm i --save-exact`

~ https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-install

Comment: this command saves the exact version information in `package.json` which will then be honored by future `npm i` runs, but it doesn't use `package-lock`.