# How do I npm update dependency versions in the package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-update

As in the title, but:

- If it is possible, I don't want to hand-rewrite the version string manually in the package-lock.json,
- I tried the following: [How do I update each dependency in package.json to the latest version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16073603/how-do-i-update-each-dependency-in-package-json-to-the-latest-version) but of course as expected, it only updated the package.json file,
- I looked at the docs: [package-lock.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json) and [package-locks explanation docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-locks),
- as written in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json), the npm install behaviour was changed in npm v5.1.0, which if I'm correct, means that if I have npm version higher than 5.1.0, my app will (by default) always npm install from tha package.json, instead of the package-lock.json. However, I still have a dependency listed in my package-lock.json which has a vulnerability, and my github is screaming warning for it.

How to best solve this? If I'm installing from package.json anyway, is it a good practice to just delete the package-lock.json? Should I rather keep it updated? What to do if I want to use the lock instead?

I have never done anything like this before, so I'm not even sure that if I just rewrote a version string in the json it would work or break the npm install.

**Is there a safe/professional way to change to package-lock.json, and keep it updated via npm?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want update version in package-lock.json,you can do it by updating the package using

```
npm update <package_name>
```

- '^' >> "Approximately equivalent to version"
- '~' >> "Compatible with version"

Read more about '^' and '~' in your package.json >> [Reference](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json)

As the package-lock specifies a version, location and integrity hash for every module and each of its dependencies, the install it creates will be the same, every single time for each user in shared project.

[Everything You Wanted To Know About package-lock.json](https://medium.com/@Quigley_Ja/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8)

Hope this will help you clear your thoughts.