# Using "npm ci" instead of "npm install" for deterministic project setup

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-ci

Given a project where the `package-lock.json` is managed in source control with the goal that all developers on the team get exactly the same dependencies.

From the documentation of npm I think developers should use `npm ci` to set up their development environment and probably also later when dependencies are updated.

However the instructions I see in typical npm projects is still to use `npm install`.

Is there a reason developers should use `npm install` instead of `npm ci`? Does `npm ci` have disadvantages in this scenario?

I understand that `npm ci` does delete the whole `node_modules` and therefore potentially re-download some dependencies that were already present.

But with `npm install` I had regularly the case that an `npm install` is actually changing the `package-lock.json` (see links below), which is definitely not what is expected in a traditional project setup, where the main goal is that all developers get the same environment.
Therefore I would like to recommend to use `npm ci`.

Examples of "unexpected" behavior of `npm install`:

- [Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17722
- https://npm.community/t/package-lock-json-keeps-changing-between-platforms-and-runs/1129/3
- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20434
- https://npm.community/t/package-lock-json-changes-from-one-npm-install-to-the-next/1454

Comment: It's a good thing that the package lock is updated with every install IMO - think about bugfixes and security updates of dependencies you would be missing if you were to freeze the exact same version forever

Comment: @PatrickHund Yes. But this should be in a controlled manner not "accidentally" by running npm install at a certain point in time. In a "traditional" software project it is essential that all team members have exactly the same environment. Else we get non-deterministic behavior. That is the main point of having a lock file.

Comment: jbandi if you are using a recent npm, (after 5.4.2) you should not see package-lock  changes. If you are seeing some changes that could only be because of different package-lock formats used in different npm versions. Or because of differences in OSs. (some dependencies are optional in some OSs) The versions of dependencies should not update.

Comment: @PatrickHund Its a bad thing. The whole point of lock files is to avoid that. We do have to update lock files time to time. Like on a major release. But if every npm i updates the lock file we might as well not use them at all.

Comment: @ArunaHerath Thanks! So `npm install` has improved ... but is there a reason *NOT* to use `npm ci`? If you write this in an answer, I will accept it ...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `npm ci` (clean install) whenever you want a reproducible environment. You are right: the dev team should use it most of the time.

Use `npm install` only when they modify the packages or are ready to upgrade dependencies (one of them does it and fixes conflicts; after the commit of `package.json` AND `package-lock.json`, the others keep doing `npm ci`).

Please, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155) explaining the uses of each tool.

Answer (score 0):

There **isn't** a reason to use `npm ci` instead of `npm i` when building a repo locally or updating dependencies (because it uses the npm cache, it's roughly the same speed as `npm i`), but there are the following situations where `npm i` might be preferred:

1. You actually *want* to receive minor/patch updates of your direct dependencies automatically;
2. if you've made manual changes to versions in `package.json` and want them to trump the versions in `package-lock.json`.

Comment: If you are a solo developer, it is probably OK. If not, `npm ci` prevents a lot of "it works on my computer" weird issues. On the other hand, `npm ci` cannot update individual dependencies; that is the function of `npm install`.