# Why does `package-lock.json` causes a failure in a docker container build when `npm install`?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, package-lock.json

There are a lot of people online asking this same question in different ways but there is no clear answer. Can anybody understand enough to explain why a `docker build` fails when `package-lock.json` file exists in the application, but runs successfully when it is not? Seemingly it is related to npm but it is not clear.

[Everybody](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16861) says delete the `package-lock.json`, but it is there for a reason.

**Note:** `npm install` works fine on my local machine, just fails in docker container.

If I have this Dockerfile:

```
# First Stage: Builder
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

And run this:

```
docker build -t container-tag ./
```

I get this:

```
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eventsource-c2615740/example/index.html'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/eventsource-c2615740/example/sse-client.js'
npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/node_modules/.staging/react-router-a14663ae/README.md'
```

But this Dockerfile will run successfully:

```
# First Stage: Builder
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./       #<-------- note that there is no star here
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

Comment: I'm not sure it answers your question that's why it's a comment, but I'm focusing on this part: "Note: npm install works fine on my local machine, just fails in docker container". If you are using `npm install` you are not sure to have the same version of dependencies That's what the package-lock.json was intended for, For having a reproducible environment, with unexpected issues because of versioning, you should use `npm ci` instead. If this doesn't fix your issue, you need to keep investigating, but IMO it should be the first step. Hope it helps.

Comment: Makes sense - I didn't know about `npm ci`, will learn more about it - Thanks so much

Answer (score 20):

From your question:

> Note: npm install works fine on my local machine, just fails in docker container

If you are using `npm install`, you are not sure to have the same version of dependencies.

**For having a reproducible environment, without unexpected issues because of different version of dependencies, you'd rather use [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html) (clean-install):**

> This command is similar to [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), except it’s meant to be used
> in automated environments such as test platforms, continuous
> integration, and deployment – or any situation where you want to make
> sure you’re doing a clean install of your dependencies. It can be
> significantly faster than a regular npm install by skipping certain
> user-oriented features. It is also more strict than a regular install,
> which can help catch errors or inconsistencies caused by the
> incrementally-installed local environments of most npm users.
>
> In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci
> are:
>
> - The project must have an existing **package-lock.json** or
>   **npm-shrinkwrap.json**.
> - If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in **package.json**, **npm ci** will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.
> - **npm ci** can only install entire projects at a time: individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.
> - If a **node_modules** is already present, it will be automatically removed before **npm ci** begins its install.
> - It will never write to **package.json** or any of the package-locks: installs are essentially frozen.

A [Fabian Gander's article](https://medium.com/@Cyclodex/demystifying-npm-install-npm-ci-package-lock-json-2807fc0ee404) gives further clarification about the `npm install` and `npm ci` tools and provides advice on when to use each one. The below table is from that source:

```
  cases                                | npm install | npm ci
 --------------------------------------|-------------|-------------
  needs package.json                   | no          | yes
  needs package-lock.json              | no          | yes
  installs from package.json           | yes         | no
  installs from package-lock.json      | no          | yes
  compares both                        | no          | yes
  updates loose package versions       | yes         | no
  updates loose dependencies           | yes         | no
  writes to package.json               | yes         | no
  writes to package-lock.json          | yes         | no
  deletes node_modules before install  | no          | yes
  used for installing separate package | yes         | no
  should be used on build systems / CI | no          | yes
  can be used for development          | yes         | yes
  reproducible installs                | no          | yes
```

This is why **package-lock.json** is there, to be available for tools like  `npm ci`.

After having a reproducible environment, if this doesn't fix your issue, you need to keep investigating, but IMO it should be the first step.

Answer (score 2):

Some reasons your local build succeeded but the Docker build failed could have been (in order of likelihood)

- you've overwritten the Alpine Linux version of your `node_modules` folder with the `node_modules` folder from your host, because you didn't `.dockerignore` `node_modules` and issued a COPY / ADD command when `node_modules` exists in `.` on the host

However, I can't explain why omitting the `package-lock.json` from the COPY would then make the build work. So the problem could also have involved:

- when you generated your `package-lock.json`, you `npm install`-ed locally under a different version of node than specified in your Dockerfile
- when you generated your `package-lock.json`, you built locally under a different operating system than Alpine Linux
- when you generated your `package-lock.json`, you `npm install`-ed locally under a different version of npm from the Docker container, it may have treated the lockfile relationship differently

All of these actions potentially will cause a `package-lock.json` to be generated that may cause an `npm install` (and more likely cause a `npm ci`) in the container to fail. I'm not sure why these would cause the specific errors you posted though.

If these reasons could be the issue, the proper solution to the problem is surely to do all your npm manipulation (including your generation and manipulation of `package.json` and `package-lock.json`) **inside** the same specification of docker container that you intend to ship the code in, and [work out a way to commit the results to source control from there](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyddZyc8r48). This can be complicated by issues like there being several needs to build your `node_modules` in the same environment you push source-code changes from (for instance a build step whose results need pushing into the container, or a git hook that needs installing). I've not yet seen a perfect solution to this issue