# TSC not found in Docker build

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When building an image that needs to be compiled from typescript, I get this error.

> sh: 1: tsc: not found

> The command '/bin/sh -c npm run tsc' returned a non-zero code: 127

Here is the relevant code:

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  nodeserver:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
      - ./public:/app/public
      - ./templates:/app/templates
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15.11.0 AS base
EXPOSE 3000
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production && npm cache clean --force

##########################################################################################

FROM base AS dev

ENV NODE_ENV=development

RUN npm install --only=development

CMD npm run dev

##########################################################################################

FROM dev AS source

COPY dist dist
COPY templates templates
COPY public public

RUN npm run tsc

##########################################################################################

FROM base AS test

COPY --from=source /app/node_modules /app/node_modules
COPY --from=source /app/templates /app/templates
COPY --from=source /app/public /app/public
COPY --from=source /app/dist /app/dist

CMD npm run test

##########################################################################################

FROM test AS prod

CMD npm start
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nodeserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./dist/app.js",
    "deploy": "git add . && git commit -m Heroku && git push heroku main",
    "tsc": "tsc --outDir ./dist",
    "dev": "npm run ts-watch",
    "test": "npm run jest --runInBand",
    "ts-watch": "tsc-watch --project . --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"nodemon ./dist/app.js\""
  },
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/MiquelPiza/nodeserver.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/MiquelPiza/nodeserver/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/MiquelPiza/nodeserver#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.19",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "socket.io": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.11",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.10.3",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.33",
    "@types/sendgrid": "^4.3.0",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "tsc-watch": "^4.2.9",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "15.11.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es5", 
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

This dockerfile works:

```
FROM node:15.11.0 AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
ADD . .
RUN npm run tsc


FROM node:15.11.0
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --production

ADD public ./public
ADD templates ./templates
COPY --from=build /app/dist dist

EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm start
```

I'm using this dockerfile for reference, from a Docker course: https://github.com/BretFisher/docker-mastery-for-nodejs/blob/master/typescript/Dockerfile
I don't see what I'm doing wrong, the source stage should have the dev dependencies, among them typescript, so it should be able to run tsc.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT:

In addition to using npm ci instead of npm install, I had to copy tsconfig.json to the working directory (and copy src directory instead of dist, which is created by tsc) for tsc to work properly. This is the modified source stage in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM dev AS source

COPY src src
COPY templates templates
COPY public public
COPY tsconfig.json tsconfig.json

RUN npm run tsc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**EDIT 2:**

This [issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2606) has been [resolved](https://github.com/npm/arborist/pull/287).  If your package-lock.json file is corrupted, you may be able to fix it with the utility [fix-has-install-script](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-has-install-script).

**Original Answer:**

Use `npm ci` (or add `package-lock.json` to your `.dockerignore` file, or delete `package-lock.json` in your local environment before building).  The **why** is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63835731/why-does-package-lock-json-causes-a-failure-in-a-docker-container-build-when).

**EDIT 1:**

Here's what I believe is going on.  Disclaimer, I'm not an expert on `nodejs` or `npm` -- in fact I'm something of a novice.  And all of this is conjecture based on some experiments.

### What's going wrong?

`npm` is not linking the binaries for the dev dependencies via sym links in `node_modules/.bin` because the `package-lock.json` file has gotten into a corrupted state where the (prod) dependencies are in lockfileVersion 2 format, and the dev dependencies are still in lockfileVersion 1 format.

### Why is this happening?

*Note:* Making a bunch of assumptions here.

1. Your local host using using npm 6, and the docker container is using npm 7.
   Because of this, the existing `package-lock.json` is in `lockfileVersion: 1` which doesn't include a `bin` section for dependencies that have binaries.  Version 2 does save the `bin:` section, which `npm` must use to determine what binaries to install/link.
2. When you run the production dependency install (e.g. `NODE_ENV=production npm install`), using `npm` version 7, `npm` is upgrading the version of your `package-lock.json` to `lockfileVersion: 2`, part of this includes saving `bin:` sections for the dependencies that install binaries.  Importantly, it updates **only the production dependencies**.  Now the `package-lock.json` file is corrupted because it claims to be in version 2 format, but all the dev dependencies are either still in version 1 or at least don't have the `bin:` section correctly applied.
3. When you now try to install your dev dependencies, `npm` sees that the `package-lock.json` is in `lockfileVersion: 2`, so it assumes that the dev dependencies have been upgraded as well (but they haven't been, or at least not correctly).  It doesn't find the `bin:` sections because they don't exist and so it doesn't link the binaries to the `node_modules/.bin/` directory.

You can perform a minimum reproduction of it using this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:14 as npm6
WORKDIR /app
# Create a node project using npm 6 and install a dev dependency
# that contains a binary.
RUN npm init --yes && \
    npm install --save-dev typescript

FROM node:15 as npm7
COPY --from=npm6 /app/package*.json /app/
WORKDIR /app
# Install production dependencies, then all dependencies. This should
# link the binaries for typescript in (e.g. tsc) under node_modules/.bin.
RUN npm install -g npm@7.10.0 && \
    npm install --production && \
    npm install

# Causes error, tsc not found.
CMD ["npx", "-c", "tsc --version"]
```

I couldn't find an existing bug ticket so I created one [here](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3125).  Perhaps it will get fixed.

Comment: I don't understand why removing package-lock.json would work. Doesn't npm ci need package-lock.json?

Comment: @mikepa88 seems like an issue with different versions of `npm` and `package-lock.json` format, I edited my answer with some more details.  In my limited experience `package-lock.json` is often the cause of bugs and dependency issues in `npm` and one of the first things I do to debug anything related to node dependencies is get rid of it.

Answer (score 32):

It's probably a `NODE_ENV` environment variable problem.

```
ENV NODE_ENV=production
```

If you set this way, the dependencies in `devDependencies` will not be installed.

Comment: Solved my problem, after moving the `ENV NODE_ENV=production` line to be between `RUN npm ci` and `RUN npm run build`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, solved the issue !

Comment: if you want to reduce your image size you can run `RUN npm prune --production` after you have done the tsc compile step

Answer (score 2):

Manually install typescript on the container

```
RUN npm install --only=production && npm cache clean --force && npm install -g typescript
```

Comment: this will install a global typescript instance which may fix things but is not the heart of the problem. issues around dev/prod env install seem more likely to resolve this cleanly.