# package-lock.json is rewritten after npm install

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json, package-lock.json

I was working on a **react project**.
I cloned it in a new machine.
As soon as I ran the command `npm install`, `package-lock.json` file was rewritten completely.

- Is this a problem?
- And how should I deal with it?

Comment: Are you using the same version of NPM the lock file was created with? v2 of the lock file came in with v7 of NPM.

Comment: No I am sure both the versions are different

Comment: That's probably it, then, check for the `lockfileVersion` at the top of `package-lock.json`. Either migrate everyone to NPM 7+ or use NPM 6 when working on that package.

Comment: First google result https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json

Comment: My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64014814/10788155) addresses one of the problems that could arise.

Answer (score 6):

**npm install** can rewrite `package-lock.json` file. Probably you have dependencies with not fixed version '~x.x.x' or '^x.x.x'. If you already have  `package-lock.json` and want install packages without update lock file, you can use **npm ci**. See this [doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-ci)