# Update Every Existence Of A Certain Package Within My node_modules

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have this error whenever I install a package

`` found 14 vulnerabilities (1 low, 1 moderate, 12 high) run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details ``

So I have found out that some of my npm packages have a vulnerable version of a 
dependency called `tar`. So all I need to do now is update this package to a higher version >= 4.4.2.

I manually changed the versions of all the `tar` dependencies in my `package-lock.json` and have tried to run the following commands 
`npm i`
`npm audit fix`
`npm audit fix --force`
but the `package-lock.json` updates itself back to it's previous `tar` dependencies. I even ran `npm cache clean --force` and repeated the above command but the same result.

Is there a way I can specifically update every `tar` dependency within my `node_modules` from the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm audit fix` changes `package.json` if needed by changing package versions to compatible ones, and `package.json` defines the possible versions that appear in `package-lock.json`.

So, you can't fix version-based vulnerabilities by rewriting `package-lock.json` because [`npm install` rewrites `package-lock.json` anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json?rq=1).

`npm audit fix` rewrites the versions in `package.json` to compatible versions that don't suffer from vulnerabilities. If running `npm audit fix` doesn't fix your version-based vulnerability issues, you have to refactor your code by using versions/libs that are not entirely compatible in the eyes of `npm audit fix` (in the real world, the changes are usually very minor). You can use the help of `npm list` to get the name of the dependency that requires an invalid version of `tar`, and change the version of this package.

Comment: i know the dependencies that are causing this and i have tried updating them, but it doesn't update their current ```tar``` dependency