# How to add npm module without changing old dependencies in package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json, package-lock.json

I use `npm ci` to install npm modules and it install same package versions as in `package-lock.json`

And now I need to add `npm module` for starting write unit tests, I use this command: `npm i jest`

I expect that it should add only `jest dependencies`, but `npm` update all out-of-date dependencies of 3-5 level dependencies in `package-lock.json`

I would like to do something like this `npm ci --save-dev jest`

How to install `npm` package without changing old dependencies in `package-lock.json`?

**UPD** For example, please clone [this repo](https://github.com/iagolaguna/express-boilerplate), after that use `npm ci` and `npm i empty-module`, if you look at `git diff` you'll see a lot of changes of `package-lock.json` file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)

Comment: not sure, I asked about how to add dep without changing whole `package-lock.json`, not about `npm install` command, but I guess its impossible(but I'm not sure), if so, I'll accept it

Comment: yes it seems it's not possible directly with npm, so maybe the only solution is to specify non-wildcard versions in package.json? I'm not sure then :)

Comment: Are you sure it updates all the dependencies? I rather expect it to update *shared* dependencies of your dependency (and their dependencies). [jest has a lot of dependencies](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/package.json), so I expect the changes to the lockfile to be significant.

Comment: See this reference point: An single install of jest will introduce over 4,000 lines of lock file: https://gist.github.com/k0pernikus/80173415337931e5132616b0628c041c

Comment: @k0pernikus Yeah, I checked it with `empty-module` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/empty-module), and it updated some old deps too, I'll add repro to my question in 48h