# npm install overrides existing package-lock.json and breaks Modal

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am seeing a weird behaviour with `package-lock.json`. Once I remove node_modules and `package-lock.json` and then build them, my application works as expected. When I do a `npm install` again with just built `package-lock.json` existing, the file entirely changes removing lot of packages from the tree. When I run the server now, certain `Modal` (from `react-bootstrap` ) components don't work properly. I don't understand why this file should change and end up installing different version of dependencies which is breaking the code. Am I doing something wrong with regards to `package-lock.json`?

Every time I remove both node_modules and this file and build I don't face any issue. Only when this file is already present and I do `npm install` I run into issues.

Comment: are your own dependencies using the latest versions available? The package-lock.json is a dependency graph, and if some of your packages are "older", then you'll have "older" nodes pointing to requiring "older" dependencies, which may have breaking changes, if you have a newer version of a "post-break" dependency installed at the "top" - your package.json

Comment: Why should package lock json be different if I build it on the one just created after removing node modules? When I nuke node modules and package lock and then build everything works as expected

Comment: have you tried `npm ci` ?

Comment: I made sure there were no conflicts using npm ci. But a subsequent npm install is removing a whole lot of packages in the package-lock.json.

Comment: Just to clarify, here is sequence of commands:
1. rm -rf node_modules && rm package-lock.json
2. npm install 
3. Start server
4. Everything works as expected
5. npm install (again)
6. package-lock.json is completely different(lot of packages removed and on starting server now, Modal doesnt work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

`npm install` creates a new `package-lock.json` whenever you update `node_modules` i.e when you install a new module/package. So the overriding of the pre-existing `package-lock.json` is expected behavior.

As for the `Modal` breaking it is likely because of version conflict. If you post the 'break' error we could better determine what's causing it but this usually happens when you're packages require a certain version of another dependency.

A possible solution would be to delete `node_modules` and the original `package-lock.json` file and then run install. You can also try [`npm ci`](http://%60npmhttps://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html).

**EDIT**

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json) might be helpful in giving you more insight into `package-lock.json` files and how they are affected by `npm install`. Essentially, once lock file has been generated, it avoids updating to newer versions - until you edit `package.json` to specify a different version or range. Whatever you're trying to install you should do it from the command line.

Comment: The error on opening modal is Cannot read property getDialogElement of undefined. Close button doesnt work saying Cannot read property remove of undefined.

Comment: I am doing what you mention in last para. But then when I do npm install again, the file changes and modal breaks

Comment: Can you post the code for your Modal component? Are you using ES6? What package are you trying to install?

Comment: ```<Modal  dialogClassName="modal-autoWidth" show={true} onHide={() => hideModal()} centered>
    <Modal.Header closeButton>
     <Modal.Title> Create Box </Modal.Title>
    </Modal.Header>```

Using modal from react-bootstrap. I am not sure what package is breaking it. This was perfectly working code started breaking after package-lock.json was committed.

Comment: Added more details in comments section of question

Answer (score 0):

`npm install` changes the `packages.json` and `package-lock.json` because it tries to install newer versions of dependencies.
If you don't want this and wish to leverage `package-lock.json` and leave `packages.json` as is, try [`npm ci`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci.html).

Comment: I am running it immediately after its built (2nd run is changing it) without any scop of new packages

Comment: More detilas in comments section of question

Comment: @OliverBlue Aah ok! One possibility is that a second level dependency i.e dependency of a dependency of a...of a package you've included in your `packages.json` is not locked in a fixed version by its author. If for the second round of install you use `npm ci` this problem never occurs.