# Why does “npm install git repo url” rewrite package-lock.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am running the `npm install` in a public GitHub [repo](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master) and it has locked the express at `4.17.0` in `package-lock.json` file which is the correct behavior of `package-lock.json` file.

However, when I execute `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git` in an empty folder then a [package-lock.json](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/more_files/package-lock.json#L103) file created with the new version of express locked at `4.17.1`. I know there is a caret `^` sign in the source [package.json](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/package.json#L20) but why the source [package-lock.json](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/package-lock.json#L105) is ignored this time?

My problem here is that when I execute `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git` on the server it should create a `package-lock.json` file with express locked at `4.17.0` not with the `4.17.1` because the source [package-lock.json](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/more_files/package-lock.json#L103) file on the [repo](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/package-lock.json#L105) has locked the express on 4.17.0.

Is there any way I can achieve this i.e `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git` will consider the source [package-lock.json](https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/more_files/package-lock.json#L103) file and should not ignore it?

I am using the following versions:

`npm version: 5.4.1`

`node version: 8.9.3`

`npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/`

`OS: Ubuntu 18.04`

Side note:
I have tried `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git` with followings as well but the issue was same i.e. it locked the express at `4.17.1`

`npm version: 6.14.4`

`node version: 13.12.0`

`npm config get registry prints: https://registry.npmjs.org/`

`OS: Ubuntu 18.04`

Please comment If there is a need to provide more information on this question.

Thank you.

Comment: Why would an npm install *not* change the lock file?

Comment: Because it already created the lock file due to which next time `npm install` will not change the lock file. Does this answer your question or I am missing something here? Please suggest.

Comment: A plain `npm install` wouldn't necessarily change that file, but installing a new package definitely would.

Comment: @jonrsharpe so is there any way I can forcefully or explicitly make the lock file similar to package.json file. And if there is not any workaround then can you please answer this question with some detail sources/links to official documentation which will help me investigating further.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What? That's what it's *supposed* to do. It's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe my problem is that when I run this on server `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git` it should create a `package-lock.json` file with express locked at `4.17.0` not with the `4.17.1` because the source lock file on the repo 
(https://github.com/nabeel-nazir-confiz/package.lock.master/blob/master/package-lock.json#L105) has locked the express on `4.17.0`. 
Let me know if I can add more on this.

Comment: @Tico I can not use `npm ci` as it only looks for the `package.json` file in the same repo where it is going to be executed. I need to run `npm install git+https://github.com/nabeel-nazir confiz/package.lock.master.git`. Please refer to my second last comment.

Comment: I am also having a similar (if not identical) problem, where npm is writing a repo-url dependency into the package-lock when first installed, but it is ignoring the lock when `npm i` is run fresh (after deleting node_modules). It looks like repo urls work different in npm, and I think it might be a bug. Let me know if you got anywhere with this.

Answer (score 0):

`npm install xxx` will every time generate a new lock file. (Actually it just ignores lock file and generate each time it execute)

`npm ci` on the other hand, is the command to install packages based on lock file instead of `package.json`

Comment: thank you for the answer. Yes, `npm ci` is another option but in my case, my requirement is general i.e. there are automatic deployments on servers which will run `npm install <git URL>`. The only issue I am facing is that is there any way I can still use the `npm install <git URL>` and it should not ignore the source lock file on the Git repo from where it is installing the package and the newly generated lock file should be same with the source lock file?
Also, I am using npm 5.4.1 which will not work with npm ci.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the carrot ^ sign. Then it'll stay locked at 4.17.0.