# Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?

Tags: npm, expo

I'm Unable to execute the `expo start` command.

Error Message:

```
PS C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\OneDrive\Desktop\rn1\my-project> expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\OneDrive\Desktop\rn1\my-project

Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?
    ├─ action (C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:34:11)
    ├─ C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\commands\start.ts:135:22
    └─ expo start (C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:350:7)
PS C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\OneDrive\Desktop\rn1\my-project> npm install
added 28 packages, removed 46 packages, changed 34 packages, and audited 653 packages in 8s
17 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details
7 low severity vulnerabilities
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
Run `npm audit` for details.
PS C:\Users\Jacky Goyal\OneDrive\Desktop\rn1\my-project> npm audit
```

## npm audit report

````
node-fetch  <=2.6.0 || 3.0.0-beta.1 - 3.0.0-beta.8
Denial of Service - https://npmjs.com/advisories/1556
No fix available
node_modules/isomorphic-fetch/node_modules/node-fetch
  isomorphic-fetch  2.0.0 - 2.2.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of node-fetch
  node_modules/isomorphic-fetch
    fbjs  0.7.0 - 1.0.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of isomorphic-fetch
    node_modules/fbjs
      metro  0.22.1 - 0.63.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
      Depends on vulnerable versions of metro-config
      node_modules/metro
        @react-native-community/cli  *
        Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
        Depends on vulnerable versions of react-native
        node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
          react-native  <=0.0.0-ffdfbbec0 || 0.22.0-rc - 0.64.0-rc.4
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @react-native-community/cli
          Depends on vulnerable versions of fbjs
          node_modules/react-native
        metro-config  <=0.63.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of metro
        node_modules/metro-config
7 low severity vulnerabilities\
Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency```
````

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @matt I am unable to run expo start command please resolve

Comment: @IshikaIT may I know that what is node version you using on this app?

Answer (score 44):

[image]

1. Change expo version from "^1.0.0" to "~41.0.1" (package.json)
2. npm install
3. npm start

Comment: In step 1, did you mean to write *from "^41.0.0"*?

Comment: @Ravshan In the solution step 1 is not required.  Also you might need to update expo with "expo update"

Comment: ok, but 1. why does this work? 2. why isn't this the default?

Answer (score 27):

if anyone is still facing issues, run

```
yarn add expo
```

if you don't have yarn installed on your computer then run

```
npm install -g yarn
```

and then run the first command.

Comment: yarn add expo worked for me. If the expo is missing.

Answer (score 20):

I also received your message when installing the commands in the "React Navigation" set-up instructions and fixing vulnerabilities. The problem arises when using the command: `npm audit fix --force`. If you check the warnings after this command, you get

> npm WARN audit Updating expo to 1.0.0, which is a SemVer major change.

So, try running: `sudo expo update`

If that doesn't work, try installing expo again with: `npm install --global expo-cli` and then update.

Comment: use this `sudo npm insatll --location=global expo-cli`

Comment: 1. step: npm audit fix --force , 2. step: npm start  the steps  is solved the my problem.

Answer (score 13):

I'm also facing this error. So I run the **npm** command in the terminal.

```
npm install
```

You do not need to change the expo version. you just reinstall it.

Answer (score 10):

1. Update the Expo to the latest version `sudo expo update`
   [image]
2. Then install the updated ***npm*** packages `npm install`
   [image]
3. Fix the issues in the packages `npm audit fix --force`
   [image]
4. Run the Application `npm start` or `expo start`
   [image]

Answer (score 3):

**Error ?** you are trying to launch the expo framework yet it can't be found  installed as part of your application modules

**solution?** simply find the latest version of Expo i.e for my case "expo": "^44.0.0", then go to your package.json file in your root folder, under the "dependencies" property plug-in that Expo version i.e

```
"dependencies":{
    "expo": "^44.0.0", 
}
```

close `package.json` file, then in your root folder run the command: `npm install`
after package installation is done run `expo start`

Answer (score 3):

I simply used the `expo update` command.

It asked me

> You are currently using SDK 1.0.0. Would you like to update to the
> latest version, 44.0.0?

and I said yes, y not..

Every Thing was good to go with the `npm start` command

Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

See the expo version - default "^1.0.0" , change ==>  "expo": "~41.0.1"

Answer (score 1):

- Change expo to version `"~43.0.0"` in `package.json`
- run `npm audit fix --force` in `node_modules` directory

Answer (score 1):

here are my 2 cents. This worked for me :

1. Download latest version of *nodejs* - https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. After installing *nodejs* reboot your computer
3. install : `npm install --global expo-cli`
4. Generate a new project with - `npx expo-cli init projectName`
5. `cd projectName`
6. `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

Is possible that you need an update try this command:

```
 sudo expo update
```

Answer (score 0):

you can run the below to install all dependencies

1. `npm i`

or  to install exp

2. `npm i -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 0):

This problem I faced was because of cloning a new project and trying to run it.

Always install the modules using the below  command

I solved this by

npm install or npm i

Comment: Not really a good advice as npm install, install the latest version of any library / dependency, but if is a old project some latest dependency could conflict

Comment: I don't think npm install installs the latest version. That's simply not how npm works.

Comment: well instead it does, have a look at package.json and package-lock.json version number after have run npm install.

Comment: npm install (in package directory, no arguments):

Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.

In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.

By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json.

Comment: This is the npm install documentation from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install. Feel free to find me any link or documentation that says npm install will update your dependencies from package.json file instead of installing them.

Comment: please read the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json, on top even npm ci for me is not always working as in a project I have it did failed to re-install dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.

I simply used the expo update command.

You are currently using SDK 1.0.0. Would you like to update to the latest version, 44.0.0?

and I said yes.

Every Thing was good to go with the npm start command

thats all

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

npm install --save expo  --legacy-peer-deps

no need to edit package.json if expo version is not 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should register first on expo and then login

I had the same issue but after I logged in it was solved.
here is all about : https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/installation/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I clonned a Github repository and then used `create-expo-app` inside the repository directory. So, the command created a directory with the name of the app, but I was not in it: I was running the `expo run` command in the wrong directory.

Double check that the `package.json` is in the same directory in which you are running `yarn` or `expo run` to avoid this simple mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The same error happened to me. But none of the other answers helped me.  In my situation, I have node.js v18.12.1 installed.  But when I check with `nvm ls`, the arrow points to "system", and on my system Xubuntu 22.04, the nodejs version installed is v12.22.9.  So I needed to do `nvm use 18`, then

```
yarn add expo
expo start
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

for window users
just type `expo update` into your terminal,

Answer (score 0):

We can quickly resolve this issue by navigating to package.json file in the project folder.
Then replace

```
"expo": "^48.0.6"
```

with

```
"expo": "~48.0.6"
```

or latest version of expo.
Then in current project directory run

```
npm install
```

This will update entire package dependencies.
Then run command npm run android.

Answer (score 0):

`sudo expo update`
`sudo npm install`
`npm start`

Fixed my issue and started project.