# can't install expo cli through npm command

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debugging, rxjs, command-prompt

Let me clarify the issue: I am trying to start react native app through expo cli. So tried to start npm install expo-cli --global to install npm globally.[that's what I get after running the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJUl2.png) I got these errors:

Comment: It's OK the warnings are usual. Don't worry about them. Can you open the app?

Comment: I thought so. So I tried opening an app, but it didn't work. I receive a message saying to verify expo if it's installed.

Comment: that's what appears 'Unable to find expo in this project - have you run yarn / npm install yet?' after running 'npm start' command

Comment: Did you try to run `npm install` or `yarn install` ? Further did you check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67618967/unable-to-find-expo-in-this-project-have-you-run-yarn-npm-install-yet)