# Doesn't package-lock.json invalidate all use of ^ in package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json, semantic-versioning, package-lock.json

I'm trying to reconcile the purpose of the `^` character in package.json, and how it's affected by package-lock.json. Let's say for example, I run `npm install johnny-dependency`.  Now I have a dependency listed in package.json:

```
"johnny-dependency": "^1.2.0"
```

On repo instantiation and the first `npm install`, package-lock.json will be generated which specifies that this package is using 1.2.0, and it will also specify which versions of `johnny-dependency`'s dependencies should be used.

If package-lock.json essentially locks down the version, what is the purpose of the `^` or `~` semvr specifiers in package.json?  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566871/12010984) to the question [Why does “npm install” rewrite package-lock.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json), it is said that package-lock.json no longer locks the root level dependencies.  If so, why is it still a best practice to commit package-lock.json to source control?

I've never given much thought to this before, surely I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: That semver range information is also used by e.g. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-outdated/, https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-outdated/

Comment: Ok...that's good to know I guess...but the same thing could be achieved without the semvr ranges (for example with [npm-check-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates)).  My issue is that there's an implication that if you run npm install on a package listed as `^1.x.x`, you'll get the most up to date minor version of that package, but the presence of package-lock seems to negate that.  That is the source of my confusion