# How to have `pnpm install` install everything exactly to the specs of the pnpm-lock file?

Tags: npm, build, dependencies, dependency-management, pnpm

If you connect a Github project to a product like Cloudflare pages or Vercel, commits to the remote repo trigger new builds. These builds will run the appropriate install and build commands.

I haven't updated a site in months. But major changes have come to dependencies being used, and it's causing me so many headaches to try and go through one-by-one and address each and every issue that has surfaced.

I'm using `pnpm`, is there anyway I can have `pnpm install` look at the existing `pnpm-lock.yaml` so I can eventually build a project that is entirely the same as a previous build I had 6 months ago?

I just want to edit some text on my site and not have to make all these updates. I tried "freezing" the versions of all my dependencies and dev dependencies in `package.json` by removing instances of `^` to match what I see in my lock file, but that didn't work.

Comment: Does this problem only occur within a CI environment? If you delete `node_modules` locally and then `pnpm install` does it do what you want?

Comment: Ah, once I deleted the `node_modules` directory locally and then "freezed" the version of every dependency in my `package.json` according to `pnpm-lock.yaml` that seemed to work.

Comment: I was going to link to some previous answers about how npm lock files work, but I'm not convinced they were correct / up-to-date. If I can find time to do a proper investigation I will post an answer, but I take it for now you've sorted out the issue?

Comment: Well, I wrote a response but actually this [short answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53594050/1447419) sums it up pretty well. `npm ci` seems to be the same as `pnpm install --frozen-lockfile` which is on by default in CI environments. Couldn't see any difference by deleting the `node_modules/` folder, you just have to watch the "specifiers" and "dependencies" sections in `pnpm-lock.yaml` to see what's happening.

Answer (score 11):

## Package Management with PNPM

See also [*Why does "npm install" rewrite package-lock.json?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json)

### Semver

The [semver specification](https://semver.org/) explains how to use semantic versioning though you can probably skip to the [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versionings).

As you probably know the numbers are in the form `major.minor.patch`. If you don't mind which patch release you have as long as it is the specified major and minor version you can use the `~` prefix. Similarly, to allow any minor version use `^`.

### Walkthrough

#### Inital Setup

```bash
pnpm init

pnpm add express
```

The `package.json` will contain (at time of writing):

```json
"express": `"^4.18.2"`
```

A `pnpm-lock.yaml` is also created:

```yaml
specifiers:
  express: ^4.18.2

dependencies:
  express: 4.18.2
```

```bash
express -> '.pnpm/express@4.18.2/node_modules/express'/
```

#### Using `pnpm install`

Giving it a first run without changing anything produces:

```bash
$ pnpm install
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
Already up to date
Done in 653ms
```

Now if I change `package.json` to be exactly v`4.16.0` we shall see an update to `pnpm-lock.yaml`

```yaml
specifiers:
  express: 4.16.0

dependencies:
  express: 4.16.0
```

Adding the patch wildcard `~4.16.0` and running `pnpm install` again gives:

```yaml
specifiers:
  express: ~4.16.0

dependencies:
  express: 4.16.0
```

Note that the install version did not change. If I delete the `node_modules/` directory and reinstall, still no change.

Ok, now try updating the minor version in `package.json` to `~4.17.0`.

```yaml
specifiers:
  express: ~4.17.0

dependencies:
  express: 4.17.3
```

This time it did update the dependency and installed the latest **patch** version but did install the exact major and minor version. If you think about what the `~` means then this is expected.

The `specifiers` section in the lock file is just what we specify as the dependency in the `package.json` file. The `dependencies` section in the lock file should reflect the version that is installed, or will be installed.

If I delete the `node_modules/` folder and `pnpm install` again then we still have `4.17.3`.

### Explanation

What confuses a lot of people about `pnpm install`/`npm install` is how the lock-file works with the semver specifier:

The installed version listed as a dependency in the lockfile ***must be compatible*** with the version specified in the package file.

- If it is compatible, no changes will be made.
- If it is incompatible, then the latest compatible version will be installed.

Perhaps because sometimes it seems to install the latest version, and not othertimes, the behaviour is not clear. To state this again, changes will only be made when there is an incompatibility between the packge version and lockfile version. The lockfile dependency never has the `~` or `^` wildcards because only one version is actually installed and that's what the lockfile is supposed to track.

#### Using `--frozen-lockfile` in a CI environment

The docs for [`pnpm install`](https://pnpm.io/cli/install) describe how the install will fail if the lockfile is out of sync or needs updating.

Changing the `package.json` back to `~4.16.0` and then doing the install:

```bash
$ pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
Lockfile is up to date, resolution step is skipped
 ERR_PNPM_OUTDATED_LOCKFILE  Cannot install with "frozen-lockfile" because pnpm-lock.yaml is not up to date with package.json

Note that in CI environments this setting is true by default. If you still need to run install in such cases, use "pnpm install --no-frozen-lockfile"
```

In fact, even if I specify the installed version exactly `4.17.3`, because it differs to the specifier `~4.17.0`, then it will err. The `package.json` and `pnpm-lock.yaml` are out of sync even though the version are compatible.

Finally I will make our package compatible with the latest version that was installed with the first `pnpm add express` command. To do this I use the minor version wildcard `^4.0.0` and unfreeze the lockfile with `pnpm install --no-frozen-lockfile`.

```yaml
specifiers:
  express: ^4.0.0

dependencies:
  express: 4.17.3
```

While the specifier is updated to match the package file, the version is not chaged; it is compatible.

Running `pnpm install --frozen-lockfile` will work again, but not update the installed version.

### Conclusion

In a normal environment the lockfile will determine the exact version installed unless it is not compatible with the package file, in which case it will install the lastest version specified by the package file.

In a CI environment the lockfile will not by default be updated and will need to be compatible with the package file for installs to occur.

If you want the latest version specified `pnpm update` *will* do the update to the lastest compatible version given in the package file.

#### Disclaimer

I've tested out everything here but it is complex and I have limited experience using pnpm in a real CI environment.

Comment: Thank you for the input. So what is the correct approach to maintain dependencies versions with pnpm? I've used yarn before with --frozen-lockfile in CI, pnpm seems to suggest the same by default yet it doesn't work. Is removing all the wildcards will be the proper choice here? Pnpm seems to lean towards it being the only choice, like in the OP's case.

Answer (score -10):

before deploying your project delete pnpm-lock.yaml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this seems to answer the opposite of what was asked