# npm ci alters formatting of package-lock.json -- content remains the same

Tags: node.js, git, npm, package-lock.json

I know there are other similar questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45022048/why-does-npm-install-rewrite-package-lock-json) but in my case it happens on production server and after running:

```
git pull
npm ci
```

Then I run:

```
git diff --ignore-all-space package-lock.json
```

There is no output indicating both files are the same. but still `git status` complains:

```
oltsm@oltsm:~/oltsm2$ git status 
On branch master 
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
    
Changes not staged for commit:   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)   (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
modified:   package-lock.json
    
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Since I want zero changes on production server from what the repo have, is there any clean way to avoid that file being modified by npm? I mean using Node own tools/configuration. I know I could write an script that does:

```
git pull && npm ci && git checkout
```

but I am not sure if I should do that.

The only extra hint I can give is this:

My local machine has:

```
rudy@rudy:~/37sur/oltsm2$ npm -v
10.4.0
```

While production has:

```
oltsm@oltsm:~/oltsm2$ npm -v

10.2.1
```

### Edit

On production:

```
oltsm@oltsm:~/oltsm2$ head package-lock.json 
{
    "name": "oltsm2",
    "lockfileVersion": 3,
    "requires": true,
    "packages": {
        "": {
            "dependencies": {
                "https": "^1.0.0",
                "myjsunit": "file:../myjsunit",
                "mysql": "^2.18.1",
```

On my local machine:

```
rudy@rudy:~/37sur/oltsm2$ head package-lock.json 
{
  "name": "oltsm2",
  "lockfileVersion": 3,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "dependencies": {
        "https": "^1.0.0",
        "myjsunit": "file:../myjsunit",
        "mysql": "^2.18.1",
```

### Edit 2

After doing more digging, found [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5694) which gives me the clue that there is no easy solution for this particular problem.  I do not mind using tabs, 2, 4, 8 or 9 spaces as long as is consistent among different installations.

### Edit 3

Per @joanis request:

Production machine:

```
root@oltsm:~# uname -a
Linux oltsm 6.1.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.55-1 
(2023-09-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@oltsm:~# node -v
v20.9.0
root@oltsm:~# npm -v
10.2.1
root@oltsm:~# cat /etc/debian_version 
12.5
```

On my local machine:

```
rudy@rudy:/usr/bin$ uname -a
Linux rudy.local 5.19.17 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Oct 24 13:00:29 CDT 2022 x86_64 Intel(R) Celeron(R) G4930 CPU @ 3.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux
rudy@rudy:/usr/bin$ node -v
v20.9.0
rudy@rudy:/usr/bin$ npm -v
10.4.0
rudy@rudy:/usr/bin$ cat /etc/slackware-version 
Slackware 15.0+
```

I also found [this comment](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/3180#issuecomment-16336516) from one of the contributors of npm.

I will try to create a minimum reproducible example.

### Update

Apparently it has to do something with npm version since I made an update during the process of trying to solve it. Now it is working as intended, but I will try to create a test case with npm 1.2.0 which - I believe - triggered the problem.

Comment: [_"\[`npm ci`\] will never write to `package.json` **or any of the package-locks**: installs are essentially frozen"_](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v10/commands/npm-ci) (emphasis mine) - what _are_ the changes you're seeing, and are you sure nothing else could be causing them?

Comment: as I said just spaces formatting. I even ran npm ci on my local machine to see if anything changes but no. just on production server. git clients and repo server are linux.
I use no git hooks and I did verify that the files changes after running npm ci

Comment: as aditional hint, seems like my local copy uses 2 spaces ident while the server modified version uses 4 spaces.

Comment: Looking at the link you edited in, that's just annoying: `npm install` has liberty to edit the package lock, that's part of its job, but `npm ci` should not contradict its own documentation and reindent the file. @jonrsharpe would you agree what is OP is describing should be reported as a bug?

Comment: However, I cannot reproduce your observation locally. Can you provide enough details of your production environment for us to reproduce this ourselves? OS (platform and version), npm version, node version, and a minimized version of your install recipe/workflow that causes this to happen?